# Proof for a theorem using induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I have to prove the following using mathematical induction:

$ S(n)= \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{9}+...+ \frac{1}{3 ^{n-1} }+ \frac{1}{ 3^{n} } = 0.5 -  \frac{1}{2*3^{n} } $

I understand I have to do the following:

1. Use a base case (when n=1)
2. Assume it's true for when n = k
3. Finally assume that it is also true for when n = k+1

My problem is that I don't actually know how to construct an answer to this.. What to do with the left hand side and the right hand side of the equation.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Hint : Add $\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}$ to do the induction step

Comment: For the right hand side only or for both sides?

Comment: On both sides (see the solutions below)

Comment: Thanks guys I understand how do them now. Basically I didn't how to link the induction hypothesis with the inductive step. :)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to prove that the proposition holds for $n+1$, assuming it holds for $n$. $$S(n+1)= \underbrace{\frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{9}+...+ \frac{1}{3 ^{n-1} }+ \frac{1}{ 3^{n} }}_{\large = \;\frac 12 - \frac 1{2\cdot 3^n}\;\text{Inductive Hypothesis}} + \frac{1}{3^{n+1}}$$ and you want to prove, using the inductive hypothesis, that this sum is equal to $$\frac 12 - \frac{1}{2\cdot 3^{n+1}}$$

---

$$\begin{align} S(n+1) & = \dfrac 12 - \frac 1{2\cdot 3^n} + \frac{1}{3^{n+1}}\\ \\ &=\dfrac 12 - \frac 1{2\cdot 3^n} + \frac{1}{ 3^{n+1}}\\ \\ &= \frac 12+\dfrac{-3 + 2}{2\cdot3^{n+1}}\\ \\ & =\frac 12-\frac1{2\cdot 3^{n+1}}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Base case: $n=1$**

$$\frac 13 = \frac 12 - \frac 16$$

**Induction hypothesis: $n=k$**

$$\frac 13  + \frac 1{3^2} + \cdots + \frac 1{3^k} = \frac 12 - \frac 1{2\cdot 3^k}$$

**Inductive step: $n = k+1$**

$$\frac 13  + \frac 1{3^2} + \cdots + \frac 1{3^k} + \frac 1{3^{k+1}} = \frac 12 - \frac 1{2\cdot 3^k} + \frac 1{3^{k+1}}= \frac 12 - \frac{3 - 2}{2\cdot 3^{k+1}} = \frac 12 - \frac 1{2 \cdot 3^{k+1}}$$

Hence the proof